# Web Audio API playbackRate (sound) voice distortion

Tags: web-audio-api

If play audio file (vioce) with Web Audio API and use playback (0.75 or 1.5) voice is hugelly distorted comparing for example to HTML5 Audio element playbackRate effect. Is it possible to make changed speed voice less distorted in Web Audio?

Answer (score 1):

It's two different effect. `<audio>` and `<video>` use time-stretching. `AudioBufferSourceNode.playbackRate` uses simple resampling.

It is somewhat possible to implement time-stretching for the Web Audio API, but it's more involved (look into OLA, SOLA, PSOLA).

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, if manage to implement, will mark as answer)